# Setting up Always On Availability Groups with Windows Server Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I'm trying to setup Availability groups for SQL Server with two nodes.

I have two SQL Servers at two different locations.

I ran through the failover cluster validation and everything looked good except that it complained about each node only having 1 pair of network interfaces.

I next ran through the wizard to create a cluster and now get the following errors.

> "This resource is marked with a state of 'Offline'. The functionality
>   that this resource provides is not available while it is in the
>   offline state. The resource may be put in this state by an
>   administrator or program. It may also be a newly created resource
>   which has not been put in the online state or the resource may be
>   dependent on a resource that is not online. Resources can be brought
>   online by choosing the 'Bring this resource online' action in Failover
>   Cluster Manager."

I went to Failover Cluster Manager to try to bring it online and then get the following message.

> "The operation failed because either the specified cluster node is not
>   the owner of the resource, or the node is not a possible owner of the
>   resource"

Any suggestions of what I need to do to bring this second node online so I can continue with configuring Always ON?

Comment: What, exactly, you tried to bring online? Please edit the question and add details there. Don't answer as a comment, those are hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, SQL Server isn't even in the picture right now and you're stuck at configuring Windows Server Failover Clustering?

If that's the case, then the best place to look for further clues (as this is quite the open ended question that could take a person many hours to investigate and depend upon settings in your specific environment) would be the **cluster log**. One of the easiest ways to gather the cluster log is to use the powershell command [Get-ClusterLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterlog) it can take multiple inputs and I'd recommend using at least `-UseLocalTime` and `-Directory` to change the log from UTC to local and the directory that you'd like the logs to be output in, respectively.

Since this, *currently*, has no involvement with SQL Server the question may be closed to migrated (for future reference).